# Xcode 6 running custom shell scripts

Tags: xcode, shell, scripting, target, build-settings

When I build my target, in the information tab I can see the scheme building and the target building. At the end of the process it runs 2 custom shell scripts.

I can't find where the target or project is running these 2 custom shell scrips. I've looked at target > build phases and it's not being set to run there. I also looked at project > build settings but I can't locate it there.

I don't want to run these scripts but I don' know how to remove them! Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: yup but I know the pods project or targets are not set to run scripts. I've inherited this project on our jenkins it runs 2 scripts at the end of the build. I've removed it from jenkins but not sure how to remove it from the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> yup but I know the pods project or targets are not set to run scripts. I've inherited this project on our jenkins it runs 2 scripts at the end of the build. I've removed it from jenkins but not sure how to remove it from the project.

Pods run scripts. Here's the two scripts being run:
[image: scripts]

If you don't want to use pods anymore, use this [pods-deintegrate](https://github.com/kylef/cocoapods-deintegrate) plugin to remove all traces of pods.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue (in a React Native project) and ticking 'Run script only when installing' for the 'Bundle RN code and images' phase solved this issue.

Comment: Similar issue infact in my case app also takes time on launch screen and crashes.. its the bundle RN code and images which is taking time but wasnt taking time earlier @Janos but if I check it the RN code doesnt load and gives error in app.